# Delete an asset from Photos library

Tags: ios, photosframework

I have started working on document directory and Photos library.So far,the things that I have been able to do are:

- Saving files in 'Photos'.
- Fetch files from 'Photos'.
- Accessing files from document directory.
- Saving files from document directory.

Now the problem that I'm facing is to delete an asset from 'Photos' library. How to do that?

I read in Apple docs that I should use 'PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest' class. So I wrote the following code:

```
 [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *chng = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest new];
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:528];
    [chng removeAssetsAtIndexes:indexSet];

   // [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]];

        } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){

    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"write error : %@",error);
    }

}];
```

But It isn't doing anything. Can I get some code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the deleteAssets

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:yourArrayOfAssets];
    //yourArrayOfAssets is an array of PHAsset objects
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: That's what I have been doing but how do I declare an array of PHAsset.All the PHAsset objects are collected in PHRequestFetch.So when I pass any index of that array in the above method,the program crashes.